# JVM does not have OOM problem even if Old Gen is full

Tags: java, jvm

I saw this interesting question about JVM memory. It is really confusing. Consider this situation: keep putting a new object into a HashMap, while this object only has a String field. It is supposed to have a OOM because I didn't override hashcode() and equals(), but the result turns out to be not, JVM keeps doing GC. All objects are strong referenced by HashMap, why there's no OOM?

```
public class FinalTest {
    private final String key;
    FinalTest(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }
    public void getKey(){
        System.out.println( key);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{
        Map<FinalTest,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(;;){
            map.put(new FinalTest("a"),"v");
            System.out.println(map.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

jconsole screenshot:
[image: jconsole screenshot]

Then I deleted that print command and the result is different...

[image: after deleting println]

Old Gen usage:
[image: Old Gen usage]

The curve goes down at the last moment because the Eden Space is cleared. Then it looks like the process is blocked (Old Gen is full). Also, even though the old gen is full, it still doesn't generate OOM exception.

Why is these two situations different? Why there is no OOM exception?

Comment: How do you know that Old Gen is full?

Comment: @gudok In the last picture, on the bottom right corner, the first column of the Heap usage table denotes how much old gen space is used.

Answer (score 2):

For each iteration of your loop, `map.toString()` is allocating much bigger chunk of memory than `map.put(new FinalTest("a"),"v");` does, so toString hides the effect of map.put allocation.

Thus your heap memory chart is showing a lot of spikes because there are a large amount of String which are garbage collectable.

Change the log line to print the size, and you will see that the map.put() calls are gradually consuming all the available memory with much fewer and smaller changes each GC when the  integer->string heap is collected:

```
 System.out.println(map.size());
```

Once you have changed as above - or commented out `System.out.println` the speed of the run will increase because much less GC is needed and you will get your `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` as expected.